# Page freezes for unknown reason

Tags: javascript, json

I have recently been experimenting with [MyJSON](http://myjson.com). I was trying to make a function that grabs from my database (so that I don't have to type long text every time I need to get it), when suddenly my page froze whenever I ran the code. Based off my debugging, it does not even run the code before freezing. Is this a bug with my IDE? If it helps, I am using [repl.it](https://repl.it) with HTML/CSS/JS.

```
function submit() {

}
console.log("test test test");
function getJSON() {
    console.log("beginning");
    var out;
    console.log("start");
    $.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1fsm75", function(data,  textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var json = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log(json);
        out = json;
        console.log(out);
    });
    while(out == undefined) {}
    return out;
}
console.log("testarooni");
console.log(getJSON());
```

Comment: what is `while(out == undefined) {}` suppose to do ?

Comment: That `while(out == undefined) {}` will do it. The `$.get` is asynchronous. Look instead at using [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function)

Comment: Did you include jQuery as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's freezing because of this line
`while(out == undefined) {}`

It looks like you're trying to go for the behavior of "Wait for the $.get method to finish, invoke it's call back and assign the out value before continuing."

However, Javascript is single threaded. That means that while it's looping through `while(out == undefined) {}`, it's constantly looping it and never had a chance to execute the $.get's response.

What you need to do is to handle the Promise/Observable (I forgot which) that $.get returns.

Comment: Thanks, I will try!

Answer (score 1):

In order to troubleshoot the issue you are facing I would suggest to check the network tab in your browser (in Google Chrome press F12 to bring it up), in order to understand if specifically the GET call performances.

I would also like to suggest, in any case, to perform the same call using async  call.
An async GET call would be preferred because it is non-blocking.

Here's an example of an async GET call to retrieve data from the Endpoint you provided:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>

            async function getDataAsync() {
                let response = await fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1fsm75');
                let data = await response.json()
                return data;
            }

            getDataAsync()
                .then(data => console.log(data)); 

        </script>        
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```